# I have the same version of firefox on two laptops but they return different pages. Is this a local or remote issue or dns.?

Tags: redirect, iis, caching, default, trailing-slash

Im a bit of a hobbyist but this bug has got me stumped.

I have'nt a clue which of the tags is the most likely culprit but I suspect caching.

[dell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9HCM.png)

[asus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGrYL.png)

Comment: This is not clear. Can you please explain with more details?

Comment: Learn to use its developer tools to track down HTTP requests/responses. Those can teach you on what happens behind the scene and what might be the cause.

Comment: The images are taken from two different laptops but return different web pages for the same url ie http://www.rolemodels.net. Compare Dell and Asus screenshots. Does any one see the Dell image using FF 102.0.1 (the lone tavern) when requesting the url?

Comment: Even though I cleared cache numerous times I just tried a FF hard refresh and it seems to have cured the problem. Hold down Ctrl (Control) + Shift and click R.